# python - transform date as string to ms since epoch in pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, date

I have some dates in my dataframe as a string like:

```
0          2015-02-09 12:40:59+00
1          2015-02-09 12:44:32+00
2          2015-02-09 12:43:05+00
3          2015-02-09 12:49:11+00
4          2015-02-09 12:52:49+00
                    ...          
1923657    2021-04-08 07:45:32+00
1923658    2021-04-08 05:40:12+00
1923659    2021-04-08 08:44:08+00
1923660    2021-04-08 00:34:37+00
1923661    2021-04-08 04:53:31+00
```

I transform them to a ms since epoch like:

```
col0='startingtimestamp'

df[col0] = df[col0].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp())
```

It works, but is there a faster and shorter solution to this?

I'd appreciate a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Just use `rstrip()` method,`to_datetime()` method and `total_seconds()` method:

```
df['col0']=df['col0'].astype(str).str.rstrip('+00')
df['col0']=pd.to_datetime(df['col0'])
df['col0']=(df['col0'] - pd.to_datetime('1970-1-1')).dt.total_seconds()
```